# Add text on that field where cursor is with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two fields, subject and description and I want to add text where the cursor is. It means, if cursor is on description, it should add text in description and if cursor is on subject, it should add text on subject field.

one field is `#subject`
other one is `#description`

How I can achieve it?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light mb-1" onclick="insertText('ticket_id')">Ticket ID</button>

 function insertText(text)
{
   // here will be code
}
```

inputs

```
<textarea class="form-control form-control-solid" rows="4" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" value="" />
```

Comment: Since you've flagged it with `jQuery` as well, I'd suggest you read about these events in the `jQuery` documentation, namely, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` and `hover`. It will give you a good idea on how to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) property, which contains currently focused element, but this will already be changed when `click` event occurs, so you'll need to use `mousedown` event, which happens before the focus changes to the button.

Then, `element.selectionStart` can be used to determine the cursor location. If you also need to replace selected text in the input you should use this in combination with `element.selectionEnd` and modify the click handler accordingly.

Here is an example:

```js
ticketIdButton = document.getElementById('ticketIdButton')
ticketIdInput = null
ticketIdInputCursorLocation = 0

// In mousedown event document.activeElement has not changed yet
// which allows to keep track of previously focused input
ticketIdButton.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  activeElement = document.activeElement
  // For simplicity, let's use ticketIdInput class to identify
  // the acceptable inputs for ticket id
  if (activeElement.classList.contains('ticketIdInput')) {
    ticketIdInput = activeElement
    ticketIdInputCursorLocation = activeElement.selectionStart
  }
  else {
    ticketIdInput = null
  }
})

ticketIdButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ticketId = '#1234'
  if (ticketIdInput !== null) {
    ticketIdInput.value = ticketIdInput.value.substring(0, ticketIdInputCursorLocation) + ticketId + ticketIdInput.value.substring(ticketIdInputCursorLocation)
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea id="description" class="ticketIdInput" placeholder="Description"></textarea><br />
<input id="subject" class="ticketIdInput" placeholder="Subject"><br />
<hr>
<button type="button" id="ticketIdButton">Ticket ID</button>
```